# How to read encrypted app.config appSettings in a windows form application in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption

The story is I have successfully encrypted my app.config file using this command

```
apsnet_regiis -pe "AppSettings" D:\
```

I first changed the `app.config` into a `web.config` file, put it in `D:\` Drive, encrypted `web.config`, renamed it to `app.config` and put it in my solution folder, the problem is, when I run my application, it throws the following error:

```
Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error message from the provider: The RSA key container could not be opened.
```

I would like to know how can my program read it, I have to note too, that I used

```
apsnet_regiis -pa "AppSettings" D:\
```

To decrypt my `app.config` file, but it throws an error that states:

```
The RSA key container is not found
```

I searched for clues for this error, most of them telling me to decrypt the encrypted file on the same machine, but I am decrypting the file on the same machine.

Here is my app.config file which I have encrypted

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="constr" connectionString="Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=fuji!5M;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Training;Data Source=FMDBMS01;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings configProtectionProvider="RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider">
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
      <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
      <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
          <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>Rsa Key</KeyName>
          </KeyInfo>
          <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>DfiTaM8CAa3/LOKxgPhPg5iyzF756SOEp9mTkwGGqQAoVuLZHRepfFYGbKbz3FLI3jFv6WDg2ixwBZWeGErEGnJGMB5Etcmgmt3Ck/y0tdy0/dmm6QgaUzd7lvoZifu81G34XVoZHYX8WsPrONL5YygdUMrziV0TSgaaycpfREw=</CipherValue>
          </CipherData>
        </EncryptedKey>
      </KeyInfo>
      <CipherData>
        <CipherValue>Q/oZj8T9o76FFxO9vZ+I8X5Xq0xuaCNo9I5/4a74ZE9FTwESIA9k3ML75HnmPNfx+0okVWMmf/w7YKESUgDk1It9saudpNyetZWT/lYgRTTB4BRbMc9M1YtYBErSGn4GUPPLuj0pP+WgC3zTe+bDSpls9cdIwcwKelpu4l9hLp/VHGWui+3u1iWmHs/d+0X9BtRFTUsjyOLUEjZnlSsiEW7eK85MswVsyxqoKUGm8QWCjt/uQc13RwIy42rHrfZqG8Zwer0woye6runE2jzH7GQPi+LolYFSq6WNJgazxFvVzrqKycVpD9PJHJFBMu2FZ0ym3ZRlfpFzNNz/Nb4O/8IwKmrmPCt6GfjvvjuOrvU=</CipherValue>
      </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientAuthenticationMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientFormsAuthenticationMembershipProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="ClientRoleProvider" enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="ClientRoleProvider" type="System.Web.ClientServices.Providers.ClientRoleProvider, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" serviceUri="" cacheTimeout="86400"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
  </system.web>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Thank you and Best Regards.

EDIT: this is my 1st question on how to encrypt my connection string, it seems like I cant get RSA to encrypt and read my connection string, I can encrypt it, but my software cant read it.